# Manually Rooting with AOSP

Tags: root-access

this is my first post here. I hope there is someone to answer my question. 
First, I want to understand Android OS better not just copy some files and be finished.

I am attempting to root my Nexus 6 beginning with compiling Android for it. I was able to compile and upload all necessary images. Now I would like to root the AOSP configuration for shamu.

Currently I am able to access ADB root by replacing the boot.img with root access **but how do I do a proper Android Root and not ADB root.**

**SuperSu: How to install it properly from ADB for Nexus 6 and which version!**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want the appropriate `su` binary to be executable from the PATH, such as putting it in `/system/xbin`.  What version you use is up to you, but if you're using SuperSU then use the binary that comes in its flash package (https://download.chainfire.eu/396/supersu/).

Comment: Thank you but do you know which is the proper version of SuperSu for Android 5.1.1?

Comment: @Orri The latest should work just fine.